# Mongoose: Update of array inside another nested array element not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my mongo schema:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2"),
    "score": 2.5,
    "questions": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5"),
            "desc": "some text",
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8"),
            "desc": "some text",
            "options": [{
                    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9"),
                    "name": "some name",
                    "desc": "description 1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbafa"),
                    "name": "some name",
                    "desc": "description 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've to update the name and desc of the **option** having id as **5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9** which is in the one of the *array elements* of the **question** attribute having id as **5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5** which is again part of the data having **id** as **5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2**

Tried the following query which is getting executed successfully but not updating the option:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id : ObjectId("5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2"),
            "questions._id": ObjectId("5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5"),
            "questions.options._id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9"),
        }, {
            $set: {
                "questions.$[q].options.$[o].order": data.order,
                "questions.$[q].options.$[o].definition": data.definition,
                "questions.$[q].options.$[o].type": data.type,
            },
          }, 
          { 
            arrayFilters: [{ "q._id": ObjectId(qid) }, { "o._id": ObjectId(oid) }]
         })
```

Is tihs possible to do in a single mongoose findOneAndUpdate method?

Comment: I think it is not updating because the query is not finding anything to update, as you are searching for "_id": ObjectId("5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5") under questions and it does not have options array. Try with another id

Comment: That's for reference...when I'm trying ith 5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8 as question id, then also same result

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, I have just hardcoded object id values in array filter and it is updating the documents. I have updated name and desc as u said. Do try this out. One more thing in mongoose u have to specify the object id as "mongoose.Types.ObjectId".
Therefore in your case it would be like "q._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8").

And one more thing is that you are using findAndUpdate, try using update only depending on your mongoose version

Here is mongoplayground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/TP5iCTAC5R_

Query:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2"),
  
"questions._id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8"),
  
"questions.options._id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9")
},

{
  $set: {
    "questions.$[q].options.$[o].name": "anotherName",
    "questions.$[q].options.$[o].desc": "anotherDesc"
  }
},

{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "q._id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8")
    },
    {
      "o._id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9")
    }
  ]
})
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2"),
    "questions": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5"),
        "desc": "some text"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8"),
        "desc": "some text",
        "options": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9"),
            "desc": "anotherDesc",
            "name": "anotherName"
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbafa"),
            "desc": "description 2",
            "name": "some name"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "score": 2.5
  }
]
```

Comment: Since I already imported mongoose.Types.ObjectId, I just used ObjectId